# Typescript: importing js libraries that import json file

Tags: json, node.js, typescript, import

Some JS libraries (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) `require` json files in their code (the most common use case being **package.json**). Typescript will throw an error when importing such libraries, as it only understand `.ts` and `.tsx`.

Can we teach typescript how to handle importing json files like the way node handles it?

Answer (score 1):

TS 2.9 [added support for json imports](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/05/31/announcing-typescript-2-9/#json-imports). Just add:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

in your `tsconfig.json` or `jsconfig.json`

Comment: This not solve the problem in my case. Using a library that has an import like `require(path.resolve(process.cwd() + '/config.json'))`. To take the config file from the root path.

Comment: JavaScript works fine, however, using this library on TypeScript throws an error. It can be fixed in some way on the codebase of the lib?

Comment: Yes, IntelliSense generally cannot resolve dynamic imports like that (especially because that example depends on where the script is run from). In such cases, your best bet is to try explicitly typing the import using jsdoc